# Is it common to get a job (industry) after getting a PhD degree in Germany? (engineering field)

Tags: phd, industry, engineering, germany

I am an engineering PhD student in Germany. I am planning to get a job in industry after finishing my degree? Is this common in Germany?

Thank you guys in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, many engineers do this. In fact, industrial partnerships with academia for PhD students are much more frequent in Germany than in the US. Many of these lead to job placements following graduation. So it certainly is a possibility—most of my grad students there decided to go to industry.

Comment: What about Computational Mechanics field? Or FEM? also same circumstances?

Comment: It's a little bit tougher, but it still happens—software companies, users of those packages, etc.

Comment: You mean Phds in the field of Computational mechanics are not in demand, relatively?

Comment: I just mean that the opportunities for industry may be more specialized since the number of computational mechanics people can be small.

Answer (score 1):

It is common practice. You can compare the number of PhDs with the number of postdoc-positions and then it's easy to tell that most PhDs are going to industry afterwards.

People from industry are telling me, that sometimes they are interested at the expertise of the person gained during the PhD (e.g. if you are doing Computational Mechanics, there are many companies looking for those people), but even more because you will learn to be self-organized, you'll have a certain tolerance against frustration, you can develop first leadership skills, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In general, yes. This is very common in Germany. Broadly speaking, science and engineering doctorates are well respected in German industry and it greatly increases your chances of finding a job *related* to your given field. I studied a chemistry doctorate in Germany. All of my former colleagues landed well paid industry jobs very soon after graduating. I, however, returned home to the UK where I struggled to find any work related to chemistry in the slightest.

The situation may well be different in engineering, but in chemistry at the time someone leaving merely having completed their Diplom (later Masters) studies would have struggled to find work in industry. A doctorate seemed almost mandatory following an undergraduate degree in the sciences for employment in related fields.